# grep - ignore empty values

Tags: linux, grep, pulseaudio

I am wondering is there an easy way to ignore search result output lets say like a `$pacmd list-modules | grep -e 'name: <module-cli-protocol-unix>' -e 'argument: '`

in this case the output is giving if argument has values or if it doesn't.

The `$pacmd list-modules` input format snippet:

```
...    
index: 5#<---not this index because the module's module-cli-protocol-unix arg is empty
name: <module-cli-protocol-unix>#<---not this name though its name is module-cli-protocol-unix but still its arg is empty
argument: <>#<---not this module's arg because it is empty
used: -1
load once: yes
properties:
    module.author = ""
    module.description = ""
    module.version = "10.0"
index: 6
name: <module-switch-on-port-available>
argument: <>
used: -1
load once: no
properties:

index: 7
name: <module-udev-detect>
argument: <>
used: -1
load once: yes
properties:
    module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
    module.description = "Detect available audio hardware and load matching drivers"
    module.version = "10.0"
index: 8
name: <module-bluetooth-policy>
argument: <>
used: -1
load once: yes
properties:
    module.author = "Frédéric Dalleau, Pali Rohár"
    module.description = "Policy module to make using bluetooth devices out-of-the-box easier"
    module.version = "10.0"
index: 9 #<---this one because it is the module-cli-protocol-unix index
name: <module-cli-protocol-unix>#<---this one because its name is module-cli-protocol-unix
argument: <sink_name=module-cli_>#<---this one because module's arg is not empty
used: -1
load once: yes
properties:
    module.author = ""
    module.description = ""
    module.version = "10.0"
index: 10
name: <module-bluez5-discover>
argument: <>
used: -1
load once: yes
properties:
    module.author = "João Paulo Rechi Vita"
    module.description = "Detect available BlueZ 5 Bluetooth audio devices and load BlueZ 5 Bluetooth audio drivers"
    module.version = "10.0"
...
```

As a final output it would be nice to have something like this:

```
index: N
name: <module-cli-protocol-unix> 
argument: <not-empty-value>
```

According to the exact input example the sorted output should be as:

```
    index: 9
    name: <module-cli-protocol-unix> 
    argument: <sink_name=module-cli_>
```

...but the solution should be dynamic in case another module with non-empty args is about to be init-ed...

So my question is how to make grep output name if argument has non-empty value?
And, yes, it would be nice to have a non-script solution... ;).

---

**EDIT**

I just tried the solution as `pacmd list-modules | grep -B2 'argument: <[^>]' | grep -Po 'index:.*|name: <module-cli-protocol-unix>'` but the output is following:

```
index: 0
index: 1
name: <module-cli-protocol-unix>
index: 25
index: 26
name: <module-cli-protocol-unix>
```

...which is odd cause it gives 4 index-es for 2 modules but it must have one index per module :S

Comment: Please provide an example of source data, so we can try out your commands against a known input.

Comment: @roaima you mean the result output? The full output is the pulseaudio's `$pacmd list-modules`

Comment: This is conjecture at best, but I suspect you are after `$pacmd list-modules | grep -e 'name: <module-cli-protocol-unix>'  | grep -e 'argument: `

Comment: @iruvar in this case the argument also outputs as `argument: <>` if it is empty so how to skip if there is `argument: <>` also output expected?

Comment: @user390525 To be able to test solutions to this issue, we would need to know what the input to `grep` might look like, and we also (for clarity) need to know what you expect to get as the result under different conditions.  I have voted to close this question as "unclear" until such information is added.

Comment: The input is pulseaudio's `pacmd` util `list-modules` command output which's format is much standard...

Comment: @roaima I edited my question please see it

Comment: @roaima emm... if argument of module-cli-protocol-unix is not empty I mean not for all modules

Comment: It would be so much easier if you provided a sample of the source and what you want as the result. At the moment we're all guessing.

Comment: I added the source from index 5 to 10 modules which all the same (the output `$pacmd list-modules`'s format) for each module except the name and some more params which are not so important cause I am interested in having module with specific name and agruments set including its index that's it

Comment: I edited my question adding comments to the input to clear it up a bit

Comment: Please don't say "something like this". Give an EXACT AND PRECISE output for the input sample you have provided. And then explain which bites you want us to match. I think this is the fifth time I've asked for the same thing and you keep editing your question to provide something different.

Comment: OK I edited my question adding the exact output what is about to be in frames of the input data but, as I am saying, the solution should be dynamic in case another module (sink) is about to be init-ed :)

Answer (score 1):

```
pacmd list-modules |\
grep -B2 'argument: <[^>]' |\
grep -B1 -A1 'name: <module-cli-protocol-unix>'
```

- The `-B` option prints lines before a match as well as the match itself
- the `-A` option prints lines after a match
- if whitespace is a problem, it can be stripped with sed, for example

So the process is:

- list all the modules
- filter on non-zero arguments
- then filter on the corect module name

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is there a way to have `-e 'index: '` which is related to the selected module? I just tried `pacmd list-modules | grep  -v 'argument: <>' | grep -e 'name: <module-cli-protocol-unix>' -e 'index: '` but seems like it outputs all existing modules index-es instead of the found one :P

Comment: read the grep documentation on the meaning of `-B` and `-v`

Comment: `pacmd list-modules | grep -B2 'argument: <[^>]' | grep -B1 name: <module-cli-protocol-unix>'`

Comment: I just edited my question please see it.

Comment: See my amended comment

Comment: The amended comment... Thanks it is really close to the point :D Yes, seems like it outputs index and name correctly but I want also to have its argument ;) I mean if module's argument is not empty output module too for the module. Current solution outputs two modules but according to my question it should output one module cause only one `module-cli-protocol-unix` module has non-empty argument

Answer (score 0):

It will be unclear until you provide some sample, but you can try:

```
pacmd list-modules | grep -v 'argument: <>' | grep -e 'name: <module-cli-protocol-unix>'
```

It will first reject all strings having empty values for argument and then will only grep those lines which have `name: <module-cli-protocol-unix>`.

Comment: Thank you. Seems like it is very nearby the point. I also tried to include index with the expression `pacmd list-modules | grep -v 'argument: <>' | grep -e 'name: <module-cli-protocol-unix>' -e 'index: '`  but it outputs all modules index-es not the found ones :(

Comment: @user390525 you can use one more pipe and then use `grep -e 'index: '`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are considering `argument: <>` to be an *empty* argument then this could work

```
pacmd list-modules | grep -B2 '^argument: <..*>' | grep -E '^(index|name|argument):'
```

Output from sample:

```
index: 9
name: <module-cli-protocol-unix>
argument: <sink_name=module-cli_>
```

Comment: what grep version do you use? I have v3.0 now installed.

Comment: No, I want the argument to be NOT EMPTY; I mean it should have values like a `argument: <some_param=value etc>`

Comment: SO GIVE SOME EXAMPLES SO WE DONT HAVE TO KEEP GUESSING

Comment: OK. I edited my question adding comments to the exact input source the module(s) which is about to be extracted; But the final solution should be dynamic in case a similar module is about to be init-ed...

Answer (score -1):

Tried with below command and worked fine

command

```
pacmd list-modules|awk '/index: [0-9]/||/name: <.*>/||/argument: <.*?>/{print $0}'
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am not sure how to integrate the solution if to use the `$pacmd list-modules` utility command instead of the filename?

Comment: I am not sure how to convert it to grep? Could you provide the solution with grep util?

Comment: KIndly check edited posted

Comment: The output I have in this case is `index: 5
 name: <module-cli-protocol-unix>
 argument: <>
    index: 6
 name: <module-switch-on-port-available>
 argument: <>
    index: 7
 name: <module-udev-detect>
 argument: <>
    index: 8
 name: <module-bluetooth-policy>
 argument: <>
    index: 9
 name: <module-bluetooth-discover>
 argument: <>
    index: 10
 name: <module-cli-protocol-unix>
 argument: <sink_name=module-cli_>
`

Comment: Thank you. It is very interesting; But it doesn't extract the `module-cli-protocol-unix` params only :P According to the input format I give in my question the output at lease must have one module cause there are only one `module-cli-protocol-unix` module has non-empty argument but still the solution must be dynamic in case some new particular modules may be init-ed